# Data warehouse and changing dimensions

Tags: data-warehouse, scd

I am fairly new to data warehouses and I want to make sure my plan makes sense. I am using a star schema to capture insurance information for reporting purposes. The users want to see everything as-of a specific day, since ever field can change daily I am planning to have a record in the fact table join to a unique record in each dimension. I know that this will generate a lot of records but I am unable to think of another way to do it.

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty an SCD2 dimension. Yes it generates a lot of records. At some point it's more practical to store attributes directly in the fact. What's your record count estimate and growth estimate?

Comment: Is this monthly reporting or daily reporting?

Comment: It is going to be daily. I don't have an exact count but it will be over 200k records daily.

Comment: But that won’t be 200k things changing daily right? That might be 200k transactions daily? Regardless you’re going to need a platform that will handle this volume. Don’t bother with anything that isn cloud based.

Comment: The plan was to copy everything each day regardless of changes. We will be using a cloud based solution.

Comment: only in case of performance issue you should go with this